# It is possible to disable the search/ help function for a document in Rstudio?

Tags: r, search, rstudio, disable

For instance if someone send me a document and I open it in Rstudio is it then possible to disable the search/ help function for a document in Rstudio. i.e. so I can't get help in Rstudio when I solve exrcises? I hope my question make sense! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you simply not use the ``help()`` function? I don't know why you would want to disable the help function. Even for a test, almost no one knows exactly the arguments of every functions.

Comment: It is because my exam in statistics we can use R but it there are no aids allowed for the exam so I thought maybe the help funktion/search bar (?) is not allowed to use

Answer (score 0):

you can go to the RStudio menu-> Preferences -> Pane Layout
Then uncheck "Help" under Files, Plots, Packages, Help, Viewer. Click the Apply button, then OK. I am on a Mac, but I'm sure Rstudio in windows is similar.
[image]

Comment: Thanks! But it is possible to add it in the same document easly if I press F1, right?

Comment: Not sure, I haven't had the opportunity to use the function keys yet.